# tell git to not diff at line-level for completely changed file

Tags: git, diff, commit

I have a sample HTML file sitting in git. Recently it needs to be changed completely, so there isn't much point looking at the diff between the new and the old.

Currently the diff will display like ++-+--+--+---++, and I want it to just display --------+++++++.

Is there a way to tell git that this file change is a complete change and users does not need to know line differences, but change as a whole?

P.S. the answer showed the way in diff command, but but it would be great if I can specify permanently this for specific file in commit command.

Comment: You are trying to defeat the purpose of version control. The point of storing the diff is for in 2 weeks when you realize you completely dun goofed and you need to go back to the old version of the file.

Comment: what I mean is that when I do a `git diff` I don't want to see a whole lot of ++-+---++--++-++. I prefer ------++++++++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every commit in git stores a completely new blob for the file, even if the change was a single character change in a text file ( later on it might be packed with just delta etc. )

And you should generally not be worried about how and what git stores ( and disk space is cheap)

Update:

If you are just worried about the diff that you see when a file is rewritten, you can use the -B option with diff:

> -B[`<n>][/<m>`]
>   --break-rewrites`[=[<n>][/<m>]]`
>
> Break complete rewrite changes into pairs of delete and create. This
>   serves two purposes:
>
> It affects the way a change that amounts to a total rewrite of a file
>   not as a series of deletion and insertion mixed together with a very
>   few lines that happen to match textually as the context, but as a
>   single deletion of everything old followed by a single insertion of
>   everything new, and the number m controls this aspect of the -B option
>   (defaults to 60%). -B/70% specifies that less than 30% of the original
>   should remain in the result for git to consider it a total rewrite
>   (i.e. otherwise the resulting patch will be a series of deletion and
>   insertion mixed together with context lines).
>
> When used with -M, a totally-rewritten file is also considered as the
>   source of a rename (usually -M only considers a file that disappeared
>   as the source of a rename), and the number n controls this aspect of
>   the -B option (defaults to 50%). -B20% specifies that a change with
>   addition and deletion compared to 20% or more of the file’s size are
>   eligible for being picked up as a possible source of a rename to
>   another file.

There are more complex methods like using filter-branch etc to remove ( and modify) history, but I won't recommend those in this case.

Comment: oh I didn't know that. I am not sure why I got the wrong impression about this. Still it is a bit annoy to see messy diff between the old and the new.

Comment: Haha, you definitely don't want to know how Git stores things.

Comment: Dont like the "disk space is cheap" the space itself may be but it costs a lot more to maintain/backup/deal with.

Comment: @AdrianCornish - Like I said, when it comes to the backup / maintain state, the blobs are packed. And also, git is based on the philosophy that disk space is cheap, and hence optimized on performance.

Comment: @lulalala - Updated answer with option for git diff that you might want to use.

Comment: @manojlds my point is that the cost of the disk is not the total cost of ownership. Nothing to do with git. I can buy 20TB of disks - but now how much will it cost me to back that up. How much time will it take - how many extra backup tapes do I need to buy to store 20TB - how long does a restore now take from a 20TB backup set